# Finding an infinite trigonometric sum

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, summation

Find the following infinite sum : $$q\sin a+q^2\sin 2a+\ldots+q^n\sin na+\ldots$$  where $|q|<1$ .It would be good if you could find it without the help of any auxiliary sequences using only trigonometric formulas.

Comment: So complex numbers are not allowed?

Comment: Does de Moivre's $(e^{i\theta})^n=e^{in\theta}=\cos n\theta+i\sin n\theta$ qualify as trigonometric formula?

Comment: That formula is what I was actually trying to avoid .

Comment: Well, you should specify it in the question then. Because I am afraid you'll get a lot of answers based on this formula... May I ask why you would try to avoid it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that for $\vert q \vert < 1$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (qe^{ia})^k = \dfrac{qe^{ia}}{1-qe^{ia}}$$
Now look at the imaginary part of the above expression.

---

**EDIT**

If complex numbers are not allowed, then proceed as follows. We have
$$S_n(q,a) = \sum_{k=1}^n q^k \sin(ka)$$
\begin{align}
\cos(a)S_n(q,a) & = \sum_{k=1}^n q^k \sin(ka) \cos(a)\\
& = \sum_{k=1}^n q^k \dfrac{\sin((k+1)a) + \sin((k-1)a)}2\\
& = \dfrac12 \left(\sum_{k=1}^n q^k \sin((k+1)a) + \sum_{k=1}^n q^k \sin((k-1)a)\right)\\
& = \dfrac12 \left(\dfrac{S_{n+1}(q,a) - q \sin(a)}{q} + q S_{n-1}(q,a)\right)
\end{align}
If $\lim_{n \to \infty} S_n(q,a) = S(q,a)$ exists, we then have
$$\cos(a) S(q,a) = \dfrac12 \left(\dfrac{S(q,a) - q \sin(a)}q + q S(q,a)\right)$$
This gives us
$$\left(\cos(a) - \dfrac12 \left(q+\dfrac1q\right)\right) S(q,a) = - \dfrac{\sin(a)}2$$
This gives us
$$S(q,a) = \dfrac{q \sin(a)}{q^2 + 1 - 2q \cos(a)}$$

Comment: Is it possible to find this sum without mentioning complex numbers?

Comment: @user1978522 Have added a proof with resorting to complex numbers.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**
We calculate the sum of geometric series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty q^ne^{ina}$$
then we take the imaginary part.